# How to read file and store it into wchar_t in C?

Tags: c, winapi, io, readfile

I am trying to get info from a `.txt` file called **a.txt** with the `ReadFile()` function, which is provided by `<windows.h>`, and store it in a `wchar_t[]` variable. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT); 

    HANDLE fh = CreateFileW(
        L"a.txt",
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    
    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    GetFileSizeEx(fh, &size);
    DWORD sizeF = size.QuadPart;

    wchar_t *readBuffer = (wchar_t *)malloc(sizeF * sizeof(wchar_t));
    DWORD bytesRead;

    if (ReadFile(fh, readBuffer, sizeF, &bytesRead, NULL)) {
        readBuffer[sizeF] = L'\0';
    }

    wprintf(L"%s\n", readBuffer);

    CloseHandle(fh);
}
```

But the output I get is not what I expected. It is question marks in squares:

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Suggestion: Unless you need the low level stuff that the winapi provides, use `fopen` to open files.

Comment: does the content of the file contain wide char, or do you need to convert it ?

Comment: [fgetsws()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-fgetws-read-wide-character-string-from-stream)

Comment: I think, fopen would be helpful but I need to use finapi functions. The content of the file is "Some text"

Comment: @Nazarevsky "*The content of the file is `"Some text"`*" - but, is that text **encoded** as UCS-2/UTF-16 to begin with? If not, then reading it into a `wchar_t[]` array is wrong. Also, why are you using `GetFileSizeEx()` just to truncate off the high 32 bits? You may as well use `GetFileSize()` instead. Also, your `malloc()` is over-allocating, get rid of the `sizeof(wchar_t)` part. And your `readBuffer[sizeF] = L'\0';` is storing the null terminator in the wrong array slot, use `readBuffer[bytesRead/sizeof(wchar_t)]` instead of `readBuffer[sizeF]`. Also, you are leaking the `readBuffer`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you! Changed encoding and everything worked

Comment: *"everything worked"* - I doubt that. `readBuffer[sizeF]` is accessing an element that's outside the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious mistake in the allocation size: you should allocate space for `sizeF + 1` elements so you can set a null terminator at `readBuffer[sizeF]`.

Testing for allocation error seems safer, especially since the allocation size may be very large.

There is another problem here: `wprintf(L"%s\n", readBuffer);` You should use `%ls` to output an array of `wchar_t`, `%s` expects an array of `char` containing multibyte representations.

It is also unclear why you call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` on all 3 standard stream handles.

I am not sure about the precise semantics of the proprietary APIs you use... Using standard functions seems both simpler and more portable.

Comment: There's no version of [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) that takes a wide character string for the file name. Which is a mandatory requirement if you're accessing filesystem objects on an NTFS volume. Promoting portable code is really just saying: Let's pretend that all kernel implementations are as anachronistic as Linux'.

Comment: What is anachronistic about UTF-8? Used for more than 99% of web pages and cell phones? and macOS too.

Comment: [`fopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen) on Windows doesn't support UTF-8. Regardless, read up on the final parameter to [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) to learn what the Linux kernel is missing. It is literally written for architectures that were ancient even back when work on Linux started.